# How to filter using grep

Tags: r, filtering

I have a taxonomy file which is structured like this:

[image]

Can I use something like grep (I have no experience here) to remove elements from the taxon column?

For example, instead of:

```
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Fusobacteria;D_2__Fusobacteriia;D_3__Fusobacteriales;D_4__Fusobacteriaceae;D_5__Fusobacterium
```

Could i remove everything before and after "Fusobacterium" so it only says:

```
Fusobacterium
```

Some of the rows go to species level so I would need to remove details after the 5th level of identification. For example:

**Change**:

```
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Proteobacteria;D_2__Gammaproteobacteria;D_3__Pasteurellales;D_4__Pasteurellaceae;D_5__Haemophilus;D_6__Pasteurellaceae bacterium canine oral taxon 272
```

**To**:

```
Haemophilus
```

Comment: `sub('.*_','',your_string_here)`

Comment: Could you explain the rule to extract the relevant words from your string?

Comment: The rules of substitution as derived from the question are still ambiguous. Could you add some more details, specifically - how would you do it manually for each line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```r
sample <- "D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Proteobacteria;D_2__Gammaproteobacteria;D_3__Pasteurellales;D_4__Pasteurellaceae;D_5__Haemophilus;D_6__Pasteurellaceae bacterium canine oral taxon 272"

sub(".*D_5__([A-Za-z]*);.*", "\\1", sample)
# [1] "Haemophilus"
```

#### Explanation

We are matching the whole string and capturing the alphabetical pattern between `D_5__` and `;`. Then we are telling `sub()` only to return the captured pattern.